# Wrong multiplication in python

Tags: python, telnet

I get a string like 'x * y' using telnet from server, where both x and y are natural numbers. All I need is to send correct answer back to server. When the amount of digits is less than 22, the answer, I get from the code below, is correct, but if it is more - something goes wrong. Here is the code:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port)
while 1:
    eq = tn.read_some().decode("utf-8")
    eq = eq[:-2]
    params = eq.split()
    if (eq != ""):
    try:
        x=int(params[0])
        y=int(params[2])
        res = x*y
        tn.write(str(res).encode('latin-1'))
    except:
        print(eq)
        break
```

For example, if

```
x=5892389056261064794905 #, 
y=7028717678246449032337 #then 
res=41415939126848056288120885900543594617842985
```

and it is correct. But if

```
x=10834381661191220895731, 
y=1501035997383808848779 #,
```

the aswer is incorrect and the main problem is that simple expression in python shell

```
10834381661191220895731 * 10834381661191220895731
```

gives the correct answer

Comment: what's the incorrect answer?

Comment: Python is not C, such typecasting is not readible at all.

Comment: Note that python types are implemented as callables, not casts; your extra parenthesis around `int()` and `str()` work, but make for confusing reading. `int(params[0])` is enough, as is `str(res)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using read_some and not checking for the cr-lf just stripping the last 2 bytes I suspect you are hitting your buffer size.  Try

```
eq = ''
while not eq.endswith('\n'):
    eq += tn.read_some().decode('utf-8')
eq.strip('\n')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, fixed the typo

Comment: And what should `eq` end *with* then? As it stands this raises a `TypeError` as you are not passing in an argument.

Comment: Sorry `endswith('\n')` added.